# npm ERR! code ENOENT while using React,npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\D\web\react\practise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-scripts

[image]

When i start node package management, this problem appears:

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your code and error message text instead of images of your code? Text is easier to read and searchable, making it more suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: $ npm start
npm ERR! path D:\D\web\react\practise\myapplication\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\D\web\react\practise

Comment: Please post *your actual code* as text - images of code alone are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug - it forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken your `package.json` file is in your `src` directory. This is not a regular setup. It must be in the root directory of your application. Like:

```
myapplication
--- src
--- node_modules
--- package.json
--- rest....
```

So, move it to the right place. It seems that you are using `create-react-app` If this is true, don't play with files like `package.json`. Just play with the files in the `src` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check your the app path to be at 'D:\D\web\react\practise\myapplication'. If the path is the same at the path in the terminal, I should work. Otherwise, you use the CD command to move the current location to the app path in the terminal.